# What is the difference between mongodb and mongomapper?

Tags: mongodb, mongomapper

What is the difference between mongodb and mongomapper ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[MongoMapper](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/06/27/mongomapper-the-rad-mongo-wrapper/) is just a Ruby API for connecting to, querying, and updating a MongoDB databse.

Comment: was asking the difference - you did not say.

Comment: @David Yes, I did. MongoMapper is an API, MongoDB is a database.

Answer (score 1):

MongoMapper is a MongoDB Library for Ruby.